# Uploading large Files with HttpWebRequest (AllowWriteSteamBuffering doesnt solve this)

Tags: c#, http, post, file-upload, upload

My problem is the following:
I am currently extensively testing my application and now I got to know that it isn't able to handle uploads of large files. Of course I informed myself of this problem, and the `AllowWriteStreamBuffering`-Property is already set to false, but when I try to upload a file with a size of ~ 700 Mb, my PC freezes (I have 4 Gb RAM and I don't get an `MemoryOutOfRangeException`). Neither I am able to use the `HttpClient`-Class because I have to provide support for .NET Framework 4, nor I can chunk the upload because the target-servers do not support that kind of upload.
I think the memory problem is caused because the data I already sent (while uploading) is still allocated in the RAM.
These lines of code are responsible for that:

```
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    requestStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
}
```

How can I delete the data which is already sent but still using my memory?
If this isn't the cause of the problem, how can I solve it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several Methods, and a kind of internal chunked Upload (but the `Chunked`-Property of the `HttpWebRequest` is `false`) works:

```
            long bytesRead = 0;
            long splitBytes = 1000000;  // ≈ 1 Mb
            int dataPacks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)file.FileSize/splitBytes);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[splitBytes];
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
            while (fileStream.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length) != 0)
            {
                if (bytesRead + splitBytes <= file.FileSize)
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
                    fileStream.Flush();
                    bytesRead += splitBytes;
                }
                else
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, (int)(file.FileSize - bytesRead));
                    fileStream.Flush();
                    bytesRead += (file.FileSize - bytesRead);
                }
            }
```

It works even on servers which don't accept a real-chunked upload.

Comment: What is "postBuffer"?